# I can't send a request by POST method from angularjs to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to build small application. It contains textarea and a button panel below wich is showing when I put first letter in this textarea. I had to use isButtonVisible() method. It works fine. The problem starts when i click on "send" a request with data from textarea to data.php script by method POST (it's point of my task. it have to be send() method). When request is done, script should show JavaScript alert() with "Data saved".

My angularjs script `(ng-controller.js)` looks like:

```
angular.module("Textarea", []).controller("TextAreaCtrl", TextAreaCtrl);

function TextAreaCtrl($scope, $http)
{
    'use strict';

    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.httpError = false;

    this.isButtonVisible = function()
    {
        return $scope.text;
    };

    this.send = function ()
    {
        var data = $scope.text;

        if(!data)
            return false;

        $http.post('data.php', data)
        .success(function (data)
        {
            $scope.success = true;
        })
        .error(function (data)
        {
            $scope.httpError = true;
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: data.php location...??
i m talking about your project hierarchy

Comment: data.php is in the same folder. data.php works at the end. it shows data from textarea, and saves it in data.txt

Comment: Any error in console ...??

Comment: 2 errors:        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/Angular%20-%20Textarea_files/angular.min.js.map:1                     GET http://localhost/Angular%20-%20Textarea_files/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Fix these errors then... You can download the map file from Angular's website.

Comment: Ok. Already fixed this errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the use of '$http' inside the controller, then you can use it in the function.

```
angular.module("Textarea", []).controller("TextAreaCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.orderList = function() {
    $http.post('http://example.com').
      success(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
      }).
      error(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
      });
    };
}];
```

Comment: I changed first line for these one, but it's still not working.

Comment: How should look data.php to receive this data?